# Generate interactive dashboard for relational data in Kibana

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana-4

I am having search engine data (Searches and Clicks), there are two tables(as table field in Elasticsearch) searches and clicks. I have a mapping between them (Same id in corresponding data), now I want to generate the various interactive dashboards using Kibana, some examples are

1. Pie chart using range filter for clicked positions. (1-5,5-10 etc.)
2. Data table containing Top queries for selected position buckets from both table.
3. Data table for Top queries and their clicked urls with URL count.

All these graphs should be interactive, i.e. if I click on position bucket then search table data should be displayed as well. (Note there are no position field in search table, we have only same id mapping between these records.)

So my question is can we use Kibana 4 for such use case?? If yes, then how can I generate reports for data in two different tables? Currently we are using tableau which supports sql joins, so we are able to achieve this functionality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I also posted the same question in official Kibana discussion board. Found the below answer.
https://discuss.elastic.co/t/generate-interactive-dashboards-for-relational-data/1146

Summary of the answer. "Elasticsearch does not support joins.
You need to look at parent/child or nesting, however Kibana does not currently support either of these."